# Trying to scrub a list of elements from Wikipedia using jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wikipedia

So I'm trying to get the following list of music genres from a page like this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_styles_of_music:_A-F

From what I can tell using Chrome's "inspect element", I need to access the `<ul>` elements' `<li>` elements' title elements. I then need access to these variables so I can input them into a database (but that part I can do).

So how do I get all the ul-->li-->title elements? I'm not even sure how to connect to that wikipedia.org webpage so I can start scrubbing. I'm relatively new to jQuery but really enjoying its awesome power thus far!

Thanks guys.

Comment: Um, why are you doing this with Javascript? Is that really going to be the way to put things into the database?

Comment: Well I just wanna get the title names and then pass them to a PHP script using an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some XPath to help:

```
var snapshot = document.evaluate('//ul/li/a[1]/@title', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
```

This creates a snapshot of all nodes in the document that matches the XPath query. The above XPath queries the `title` attribute of the first link element that is the child of `<li>` which is the child of `<ul>`.

After you get the snapshot, you can iterate through it and get the names:

```
for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.snapshotLength; i ++) console.log(snapshot.snapshotItem(i).nodeValue);
```

(you can run above code in chrome's web inspector console.)

---

You can also do the same thing in PHP, just load the document in a DOMDocument:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_styles_of_music:_A-F'));
```

And use XPath to query:

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xp->query('//ul/li/a[1]/@title') as $node) {
    echo "$node->nodeValue\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FList_of_styles_of_music%3A_A-F%22%20and%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40id%3D%22bodyContent%22%5D%2Ful%2Fli%2Fa'&format=json&diagnostics=true",
  success: function(e){
      $.each(e.query.results.a,function(i,c){
          $('ul').append($('<li />').text(c.title));
      });

  }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/DW2p3/